# How can I stop my vim from indenting this much on returns?

Tags: vim, vi, neovim

Here is a screenshot for example: [image]

When I expand the parentheses I get what appears to be 8 spaces, and the formatting is all messed up. Im not sure if its an indentation plugin I use or a setting. Here is my .vimrc for reference if needed: https://github.com/Munsterberg/dotvimrc/blob/master/.vimrc-backup

EDIT: I am using Neovim

Comment: The golden rule of `.vimrc` is: _Don't put any lines in your vimrc that you don't understand_.
See https://dougblack.io/words/a-good-vimrc.html

Comment: @AmirRachum That's actually where I got a lot of my .vimrc from ironically. If you look at my vimrc you can literally see the exact same comments that are in that article haha

Comment: If you are using the filetype indent, then you do not need or want `set autoindent` also. But I'm not sure that's the issue here. Also note, you are turning on filetype indenting twice (lines 50 and 112).

Comment: @DanLowe Edited my comment to clarify I am using neovim. It also happens in MacVim though. Thank you for pointing that out, I removed the autoindent as well

Comment: The usual process in a case like this is to comment out much of your .vimrc file, especially plugins, and then turn them on one by one, testing in between each change, to figure out what plugin (or setting) introduces the behavior.

Comment: @DanLowe That was my first thought or just run `nvim -u NONE`, but AutoPairs completes '(' with a ')'. I believe that is the plugin that is causing the issue, but if I download an alternative like delimitMate it does the exact same thing.

Comment: If you comment out _only_ AutoPairs, does the indentation behave properly? FWIW, I added AutoPairs to my setup, and it indented 4 spaces instead of over-indenting.

Comment: @DanLowe No it doesn't so I guess that rules out that plugin. Im really not sure what is causing this behaviour. I talked to someone who uses delimitMate with vanilla settings and his indents properly, unlike mine when using delimitMate. Im going to comment out one plugin at a time until I figure it out

Comment: @Jake Vanilla vim javascript indentation is not able to indent such complex javascript syntaxes. you should use a plugin. so first install this plugin: [pangloss/vim-javascript](https://github.com/pangloss/vim-javascript). then remove [this line](https://github.com/Munsterberg/dotvimrc/blob/9e2434bd1d5775b5852e19d3b34c001c8e8d71ed/.vimrc-backup#L112) because you set filetype indentation one time [here](https://github.com/Munsterberg/dotvimrc/blob/9e2434bd1d5775b5852e19d3b34c001c8e8d71ed/.vimrc-backup#L50).

Comment: @dNitro This actually fixed the issue! I thought I had this plugin installed, but it wasn't. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by following the comment by @dNitro and installing the vim-javascript plugin. For anyone that runs into this issue